# pac4j.core classes unresolved in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I have cloned the demo project for pac4j play at 
[here](https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j-java-demo).
It runs successfully and display the web interface at port 9000
but the Classes from org.pac4j.core are unresolved in the Intellij IDE
[image: import statements]
this is how the import statements are shown

below is my build.sbt file

```
name := "play-pac4j-java-demo"

version := "2.2.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.pac4j" % "play-pac4j" % "2.2.0-SNAPSHOT",
"org.pac4j" % "pac4j-http" % "1.9.0-SNAPSHOT",
"org.pac4j" % "pac4j-cas" % "1.9.0-SNAPSHOT",
"org.pac4j" % "pac4j-openid" % "1.9.0-SNAPSHOT" exclude("xml-apis" , "xml-       apis"),
"org.pac4j" % "pac4j-oauth" % "1.9.0-SNAPSHOT",
"org.pac4j" % "pac4j-saml" % "1.9.0-SNAPSHOT",
"org.pac4j" % "pac4j-oidc" % "1.9.0-SNAPSHOT",
"org.pac4j" % "pac4j-gae" % "1.9.0-SNAPSHOT",
"org.pac4j" % "pac4j-jwt" % "1.9.0-SNAPSHOT",
"org.pac4j" % "pac4j-ldap" % "1.9.0-SNAPSHOT",
"org.pac4j" % "pac4j-sql" % "1.9.0-SNAPSHOT",
"org.pac4j" % "pac4j-mongo" % "1.9.0-SNAPSHOT",
"org.pac4j" % "pac4j-stormpath" % "1.9.0-SNAPSHOT",
"com.typesafe.play" % "play-cache_2.11" % "2.4.0",
"org.pac4j" % "pac4j-core" % "1.8.8"
)

resolvers ++= Seq(Resolver.mavenLocal, "Sonatype snapshots repository" at    "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/")

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

why is this happening?

Comment: Refresh the project in the `sbt` tool window, and then synchronize the IntelliJ project (File -> Synchronize) once the refresh is done.

Comment: that didn't solve it mate

Comment: Which version (number & edition) of IntelliJ?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2 
ultimate edition

Comment: I can't reproduce it in 16U.  Do you see the libraries under "External libraries" in the Project view?

Comment: i cant find pac4j-core library there, but others are present.
but i cant understand why it is working with these errors

Comment: It's an IDE issue, not a project issue. Prior to IntelliJ 15 (or possibly even 16) I often had weird integration issues with sbt projects. Did you import it as an sbt project directly into IntelliJ, or use `gen-idea` from activator?

Comment: i imported it directly.
will upgrading to 16u solve this?

Comment: It works for me.  Alternatively, try closing the project and deleting the `.idea` directory.  Then, open activator, run `gen-idea` and open the resulting project.  If that doesn't work, upgrading should fix the issue.

Comment: that did the trick!! thanks @SteveChaloner you are awesome!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the help of **Steve Chaloner**
i deleted the .idea folder and used

```
gen-idea
```

to generate the project, instead of directly importing from Intellij